# Swift: Adding more elements to my append

Tags: arrays, swift

I am wondering how to add more elements to my array 'faq'. right now it has just image but i want to string a label and other images. This is Xcode Swift.

var questions : [faq] = faq

```
var selectQuest = 0;

var doneQuest = Bool()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    questions.append(faq(fImage: "1.png") here x) or X<-- I guess in here where ar you add more elements?
    questions.append(faq(fImage: "2.png"))
    questions.append(faq(fImage: "3.png"))
    questions.append(faq(fImage: "4.png"))
    questions.append(faq(fImage: "5.png"))
    questions.append(faq(fImage: "6.png"))
    questions.append(faq(fImage: "7.png"))
    questions.append(faq(fImage: "8.png"))



    dispendserIQGCollectionView.reloadData()
    print(questions.count)
```

Comment: what is `faq`? add more variables to that class/struct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you have an array of `FAQ`. The FAQ class has an member named `fImage`. However, you want to add more members to class.

I think your class looks something like this -

```
class FAQ {

    var fImage: UIImage
    /*Rest of class*/
}
```

To add more member to the class, you need to add another member named `fLabel` to the class, as shown below

```
class FAQ {

    var fImage: UIImage
    var fLabel: UILabel

    /*Rest of class*/
}
```

Answer (score 1):

See the [Swift Documentation: Collection Types](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH8-ID105).

> Alternatively, append an array of one or more compatible items with the addition assignment operator (`+=`):

```
shoppingList += ["Baking Powder"]
// shoppingList now contains 4 items
shoppingList += ["Chocolate Spread", "Cheese", "Butter"]
// shoppingList now contains 7 items
```